# .html() how to show only selected option of select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i do $("#form").html() my output is;

```
<select id="Select1" name="Select1">
<option value="Data1">Data1</option>
<option value="Data2">Data2</option>
<option value="Data3">Data3</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Data4">Data4</option>
</select>
```

But when i call .html() function i want to get only selected option of select like this;

```
<select id="Select1" name="Select1">
<option selected="selected" value="Data4">Data4</option>
</select>
```

How can i do it with .html() function?

Comment: Why exactly would you want the string of the `<option>` and `<select>` in that form?

Comment: Did u saw my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected option by using selector **:selected** : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

```js
let selectedOption = $("#form #Select1 option:selected"); 
let selectedOptionParent = selectedOption.parent()[0];
let selectedOptionTag = selectedOption[0];
let selectedOptionVal = selectedOption.val();

console.log(selectedOptionParent);
console.log(selectedOptionTag);
console.log(selectedOptionVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <select id="Select1" name="Select1">
    <option value="Data1">Data1</option>
    <option value="Data2">Data2</option>
    <option value="Data3">Data3</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Data4">Data4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```